# Why did Doc Brown choose the Delorean DMC-12 as his first time traveling vehicle?

Tags: back-to-the-future

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigowatts), the movie makers decided

> The specific choice of vehicle was a [DeLorean DMC-12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeLorean_DMC-12) for the purposes
>   of it looking like an alien spaceship due to its characteristic
>   gullwing doors.

Is there a reason from within the storyline (comic books, cartoons, video games, deleted scenes) that explains why Emmett Brown choose that particular make and model?

Comment: He went to 2015, saw a rerun of *Back to the Future*, and realized he **had** to make it a Delorean to avoid time paradoxes.

Comment: What's a rerun?

Comment: @user1129682 when a show is on TV again, after being aired at lease once.

Comment: @TankorSmash ***whoosh***

Comment: @DrRDizzle The more appropriate response is "You'll find out..."

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I believe the storyline reason is that Doc thought that DeLoreans were stylish:

> **Marty McFly:** Wait a minute, Doc. Ah... Are you telling me that you built a time machine... out of a DeLorean?
>
> **Dr. Emmett Brown:** The way I see it, if you're gonna build a time machine into a car, why not do it with some style?
>
> Besides, the stainless steel construction made the flux disperal... Watch out!

Comment: Don't forget the line just after than. It was for more than just looks:  *Besides, the stainless, steel construction made the flux
dispersal-*

Comment: Thanks. IMDB didn't go that far and I didn't want to misquote. Added now.

Comment: This was of course a joke, the DeLorean failed miserably at market because people though the design was silly. This was supposed to show Docs eccentric nature.

Comment: @Pyrodante - I don't know about popular taste but I'm with Doc on this one, that is one helluva stylish car.

Comment: Upon further evaluation, I have found nothing to back up what I said, and it may in fact be unfounded. The company that produced the car went out of business for other reasons besides the car itself it would seem. Although, it could still be a reference to the companies failure.

Comment: I remember reading there's a company trying to relaunch the Delorean. I don't know where that stands in terms of how far along they are.

Comment: I wish I could remember where I read it, but supposedly the movie was going to use something like a time-traveling fridge or something, but that idea was ditched because of safety concerns (encouraging kids to play in fridges...) Maybe that was a joke?

Comment: @Pyrodante - the company was in trouble already when the owner got busted for being involved in a fairly large scale cocaine-selling operation, if I'm not mistaken.  The car was meh.  Everyone thought it looked cool, but apparently it wasn't much fun to drive.

Answer (score 12):

According to [this article](http://backtothefuture.com/delorean/#qHEsY7uejUQrTDZS.99) at backtothefuture.com:

> Thanks to the stainless steel construction of the DeLorean, flux dispersal is generated at an optimum level from the Flux Capacitor, providing the entire vehicle and its passengers a smooth passage through the space-time continuum during temporal displacement.

Comment: and then they bounced the graviton particle beam off the main deflector dish